# FormData Append Producing Error When It Shouldn't Be

Tags: javascript, form-data

I am getting a strange error in the console :

> Can only call FormData.append on instances of FormData

The code is as follows :

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $('#singleQuestionCSVForm').submit(function(e){

           e.preventDefault();

           var formData = new FormData;
           formData.append('type','single');
           //data.append('csv',$('#singleQuestionCSVFile')[0].files[0]);

           $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',{action:'uploadCSV',data:formData},function(r){

           });

       });
    });
</script>
```

That is it, I am using *append* on an instance of *FormData* so why is this error happening?

Comment: Without context of your application its impossible to say anything, without surrounding context this simply works...

Comment: Well, I don't think this is the code that's producing the error. The error says `FormData.append on instances of FormData`. Notice the capital F in FormData? Yet clearly you've called `formData = new FormData();` So, we'll need more context here... If this is the only code that uses it, instead of `var formData` try `const formData`

Comment: @ŁukaszBlaszyński   - added the full code snippet. I personally don't see anything wrong with this code, i've used similar many times.

Comment: Ah it's the $.post - i remember this now, jquery doesn't like FormData with post i need to use $.ajax

Comment: It won't work however you try to post the data until you put parenthesis after `new FormData;`

Comment: @Archer i know, that is a typo above, it's working now, it was $.post() that was the problem as jquery spits it's dummy out with form data unless using $.ajax()

Comment: Sorry, but that is nonsense.  The error message you posted is about using the `.append()` method.  You hadn't even *got* to the part where you post the request.

Answer (score 2):

You got typo in your code, forgot to type '()' after 'new FormData'

```
var formData = new FormData();

// or

var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('singleQuestionCSVForm'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you foget to create object currectly. Because you forget to add ()

```
var formData = new FormData;
```

It should change with FormData();

```
var formData = new FormData();
```

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out, i remember from the past trying this, jQuery doesn't like FormData using the $.post() method, need to use $.ajax() instead!

Comment: No, it is not.  jQuery's post method is simply shorthand for the ajax method.  It uses the ajax method.

Comment: `$.post` is exactly the same as `$.ajax({method: 'POST'})`